# How to set small widgets theme on Firefox

Tags: firefox, themes

When I switched to Firefox 57 I was able to choose a theme with small widgets. Today on Firefox 67 it looks like this.

[image]

In the addon settings it is just named the light theme.

[image]

When I create a new profile today and choose the light theme, the widgets are considerably bigger.

[image]

Does anyone know what I have to do to create a new profile with the small widgets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a theme; it's a separate "Density" setting under *Menu → Customize*.

[image: Screenshot of the "Density" menu]